# Timeout error in running a multi-server SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I defined a linked server to a remote server in my local SQL Server.

I run a query in join of local and remote servers as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM [RemteServer].[RemoteDB].[dbo].[Links]
WHERE Id NOT IN
    (
    SELECT ExternalId
    FROM [dbo].[Links]
    )
```

When I run this query on SQL Server Management Studio, It executes during 2 minutes, but when I run it on a C# program on my local machine connected to local SQL Server it produces timeout error.

I set `connect timeout` on C# connection string to 600. also I set `Connection timeout` and `Query timeout` on Linked Server properties to 600.

How can I prevent timeout error?

P.S: SQL server version is 2008. I use Visual Studio 2015 and use ADO connection on VS.

Comment: You should be using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx `CommandTimeout` not connection timeout. Command time out would be used because your query takes a long time to run.

Comment: `CommandTimeout` is related to `SqlCommand`, but I use `SqlDataAdapter` to get the result of executing query.

Comment: you can still use `CommandTimeout` on a `SqlDataAdapter` after you instanciate it then use `yourvariable.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;`

Comment: How often does the remote data get changed, or is it continuous?

Comment: @Mad, it is continously changing.

Comment: @prospector, I used `da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);` if I use your command prior, the da is null. if I use it after this, it is after getting error.

Comment: If you are getting a error you need to tell us what error you are getting, edit your question and include the error details.

Comment: Timeout error in query execution is familiar for C# programmers.

Comment: As I have pointed out in my answer and in other comments, I think the biggest problem in your query is the use of a WHERE clause with an IN clause that tests against a query.  Such a subquery is unnecessary and will often be extremely inefficient.  You should be able to do this query with a join to a CTE, and that will be far more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to migrate the bulk of this query onto the SQL Server, and use a stored procedure to do the work.

**SQL Server**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.lsp_GetRemoteLinks
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RemoteLinks') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #RemoteLinks

    SELECT    *
    INTO      #RemoteLinks
    FROM        [RemteServer].[RemoteDB].[dbo].[Links]

    SELECT    *
    FROM        #RemoteLinks
    WHERE    (Id NOT IN (SELECT ExternalId FROM [dbo].[Links] ))

    DROP TABLE #RemoteLinks
END
GO
```

**C#**

```
    DataTable RemoteLinks = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn)) {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("lsp_GetRemoteLinks", conn)) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            RemoteLinks.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

This should cut your times down, but I did put increase the `CommandTimeout` value.

If this data did not need to be "live" with it's freshness I would consider making a permanent local table and use *SQL Agent* to re-populate it at regular intervals, and then you would be able to use *Indexes* on the table to improve efficiency further.

Comment: Having a SELECT inside an IN clause, inside a WHERE clause, is usually really bad for performance and unnecessary.  Although such subqueries do sometimes have their uses, this does not look like one where it is necessary.

Comment: I tried to minimize the actual changes to his SQL statement, many ways to r improve SQL performance such as "missing record" join. where not exists, delete from, etc. What works for some may not be accessible to others.

Comment: I tested your suggestion for increasing the performance. Since I need to transfer all fields to local server (not only ids) your solution takes 2.5 times slower than mine(I wrote my query in question.)

Answer (score 0):

Your performance on this query is not ideal because you are essentially trying to read every record from the Linked server onto your Local server where the query is being executed.  If you can filter the results by adding a WHERE clause that will be executed on the remote server, your performance will significantly improve.

```
DECLARE @ExtLinks TABLE (Id INT)
INSERT INTO @ExtLinks (Id)
SELECT ID 
FROM [RemteServer].[RemoteDB].[dbo].[Links]
--WHERE Princess = 'Zelda'

SELECT * FROM @ExtLinks
WHERE Id NOT IN
    (
    SELECT ExternalId
    FROM [dbo].[Links]
    )
```

Comment: my problem is: how to increase executing query timeout. not how to increase our performance.

Comment: In addition your solution even is not increasing performance. because we need all fields to be transfer to local, not only Id.

Comment: Increasing your query timeout only masks the immediate problem.  As the linked server table grows, query performance will degrade, requiring you to continuously increase your query timeout, negatively impacting the end-user experience.

Comment: Filtering the data on the linked server makes your job easier in the long-run.  You can also add more fields if you want.  The table variable example is only to illustrate the point.

Comment: I test it. but I think in both situations (my query and yours) it is necessary to transfer ids of local table to remote and all data of selected row on remote to local. so the time may not differs in these solutions.

Comment: @AmirZojaji Fix the problem, not the symptom; if the query can run faster (problem) then you don't need to increase the timeout (bandage) because it take's too long to run (symptom).

Comment: I tested it. My query doesn't find any increase in performance. the only cause of taking much time is large volume of data. I increased the timeout by helping you @Mad.